# How can I pass a boolean in the Http call to an ASP.NET method?

Tags: asp.net, http, asp.net-web-api

Here is what I have so far:

```
[Route("EndTest/{examId:int}/{userTestId:int}/{retrieve:boolean}")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> EndTest(int examId, int userTestId, bool retrieve)
```

Can someone validate if this is the correct way to do this, if it is even possible and if so then how could I pass the boolean with a Http call?

Answer (score 1):

According to this [Route Constraints](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#constraints) you need to change `boolean` to `bool`.

```
//eg: GET /EndTest/1234/56789/true
[HttpGet]
[Route("EndTest/{examId:int}/{userTestId:int}/{retrieve:bool}")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> EndTest(int examId, int userTestId, bool retrieve) {...}
```

It is also good practice to indicate what  HTTPMethod is allowed when [adding route attributes](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#add-routes) that do not conform to the default convention used by the framework. I added `HttpGetAttribute` in my example.